# Selenium: how to call method (taking screenshot) from another class

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a class with tests (using Selenium, TestNG, JAVA) with following structure:

```
public class loggedTest {

@Test

@Test

@AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(messages screen, ITestResult result) {
        screen.screenshot(result);
}
```

In AfterMethod I want to make a screenshot if test failed.
Here is this method for making screenshot in a separate class:

```
public class messages {
    public void screenshot(ITestResult result) {

        //driver = new ChromeDriver();
        if (ITestResult.FAILURE == result.getStatus()) {
            try {
                TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
                File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                Date date = new Date();
                FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File("./Screenshots/" + result.getInstanceName() + "." + result.getName() + "." + date + ".png"));
                System.out.println("Screenshot taken");
            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println("Exception while taking screenshot " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am running tests, but **it does not work**, if this method is in other class.

But **it is working** if I put it right into @AfterMethod annotation, like that:

```
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown(ITestResult result) {


  if (ITestResult.FAILURE == result.getStatus()) {
    try {
        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        Date date = new Date();
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File("./Screenshots/" + result.getInstanceName() + "." + result.getName() + "." + date + ".png"));
        System.out.println("Screenshot taken");
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Exception while taking screenshot " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Where is the problem here?
Thanks

Comment: the only suspect I could think of, does you `messages` class know what `driver` is?

Comment: please update the thread if the problem was resolved or not.

Answer (score 2):

Why is the `.screenshot()` function in a class called `messages`? It doesn't seem like it should belong there or `messages` should be renamed.

One way to fix this is to create a `Utils` class, make it `static`, and then put the `.screenshot()` function in there and call it like `Utils.screenshot()` from `.tearDown()`.

Answer (score 1):

Few things -

1. Improve on writing class names

   `loggedTest` -> `LoggedTest`

   `messages` -> `Messages`(as referred herafter)
2. You need not pass the instance of `Messages` to `tearDown()`, rather make a call to the `screenshot` method as -

   ```
   @AfterMethod
   public void tearDown(ITestResult result) {
       new Messages().screenshot(result);
   }
   ```
3. Make sure your `Messages` class understands what existing `driver` is. Unless you end up creating a new driver and doing things absurd. Suggesting - You can probably pass on the instance of `driver` in a static context or using a super class there.